# setting up user access to localhost in SSRS 2014

Tags: ssrs-2014

I have an instance of SSRS 2014 running on Windows Server 2012r2 and cannot seem to properly grant access to the localhost reportserver to myself.  I have admin rights to the server.  I have logged into the server and run IE as administrator in order to grant my username all site-wide roles (System Administrator, System User) as well as all roles for the Home folder.  Yet when I run IE not as administrator and attempt to access the reportserver, I get:

User 'servername\myusername' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

I have tried rebooting the server (just in case) - no help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question by following the directions here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2014/03/06/configuring-native-mode-ssrs-on-local-host/

Specifically I used SQL Reporting Services Configuration to add a Report Manager HTTP URL.